# Comparing dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, pattern-matching

I have two separate pandas dataframes (`df1` and `df2`) which have multiple columns with some common columns.

I would like to find every row in `df2` that does not have a match in `df1`. Match between `df1` and `df2` is defined as having the same values in two different columns A and B in the same row.

df1

```
A    B     C     text
45   2     1     score
33   5     2     miss
20   1     3     score
```

df2

```
A    B    D       text
45   3    1       shot
33   5    2       shot
10   2    3       miss
20   1    4       miss
```

Result df (Only Rows 1 and 3 are returned as the values of A and B in `df2` have a match in the same row in `df1` for Rows 2 and 4)

```
A    B    D       text
45   3    1       shot
10   2    3       miss
```

Is it possible to use the `isin` method in this scenario?

Comment: Can you clarify the rules?  It looks like you are selecting rows from df2 whenever EITHER column A OR column B has the same value present anywhere in df1.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
# set index (as selecting columns)
df1 = df1.set_index(['A','B'])
df2 = df2.set_index(['A','B'])

# now .isin will work
df2[~df2.index.isin(df1.index)].reset_index()

    A   B   D   text
0   45  3   1   shot
1   10  2   3   miss
```

Comment: In addition to comparing values in columns A and B, if I also wanted to make additional comparisons..like.. all factors of the number in Column A in "df2" with the number in Column B before deciding that there is no match, are there any operators I can use? Sorry, I am new to Python and overwhelmed with the number of functions and options.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question completely. Could you please provide an example and output?